# What .NET UI Testing tool has a built in browser to run tests faster?

Tags: selenium, watin, coded-ui-tests, acceptance-testing

Hello
I remember seeing once that either selenium or watin have a "built in" browser to run tests quicker than it usually takes with a usual browser (IE/FF...), was I dreaming or is it true? Can anyone direct me to some info/docs on the issue?

thanks,
n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be thinking of the use of the [HtmlUnit project](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). HtmlUnit is a so-called "headless" browser written in Java. As such, it simulates the actions of loading a page in a browser without actually rendering anything to the screen. The Selenium project does have a Java driver for HtmlUnit, allowing you to load your web pages in it and simulate users therein. There is no real .NET equivalent to HtmlUnit. You can use the Java HtmlUnit driver from C# via the RemoteWebDriver class, but you'll still require an instance of the Java remote server running to use it.

Answer (score 0):

WatiN does not have such a thing. You could use WebBrowser WinForms control though.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't use a 'built in' browser.  It will launch the browser it is configured to test with.